# Cursor get stuck at the statusline bar when saving a .tex file (probably due to vimtex)

Tags: statusline, save, plugin-vimtex, wsl

To preface this, I'm relatively new to vim, and I'm using Windows Subsytsem for Linux, and the Windows Terminal if this makes any difference.

So whenever I'm editing a `.tex` file and want to save, after pressing `:q`, my cursor is stuck at the statusbar line. Whatever I type gets written there, and I can only exit this state by pressing `<C-D>` if I haven't typed anything yet in the statusbar. If I typed anything else I have to close vim by pressing `<C-Z>` because `<C-D>` won't work.
[image]

The black lines at the bottom are when I'm pressing `enter`, basically "pushing my vim up", and showing me my Windows Terminal.

This has been happening for a while, but I finally noticed that it was only happening when editing `.tex` files. I'm guessing this is due to my `vimtex` plugin, because this is the only plugin that I have for `.tex` files.

Here is what in my `.vimrc` regarding `vimtex`, but I doubt it's related to that since this seems like basic configuration (I set this up a long time ago so I forgot what these actually do).

```
let g:vimtex_view_general_viewer = 'SumatraPDF.exe'
let g:vimtex_view_general_options = '-reuse-instance @pdf'
let g:vimtex_view_general_options_latexmk = '-reuse-instance'
```

If you need me to show all my `.vimrc` tell me, but I doubt there's an issue there since it's pretty basic for a beginner like me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: could it be some background job, trying to run something that makes Vim unresponsive?

Comment: If that would be the case, it should some background process that vimtex uses. Vimtex allows for instant pdf update after saving. So I can just `:w` and then my pdf updates automatically. Would it be maybe something related this? And how can I check said background process? I tried `$ps -e` and the only relevant processes are pdflatex and latexmk.

Comment: I don't know. Check the documentation